# how can I send certain data from 1 .csv file to another with powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

With Powershell, I need to get data from a .csv file and filter that then write it to another .csv file for use by a different script.
Scenario: first.csv has 2 columns "PSComputername" and "BuildNumber". I need to send only the "PScomputername" that dont match a certain ""BuildNumber to another .csv file. what I have now gets the "PScomputername" but it gets all of them, ignoring the if statement.

```
    $computers = Import-csv "c:\scripts\os.csv"

    
    foreach ($computer in $computers){
      
      if ($computers.BuildNumber -ne ("19045"))
      
      {
      }
      }
    $computers.PSComputerName | Out-file "c:\scripts\noncompliant.csv"
```

Comment: Your loop is doing practically nothing

Comment: Yes I know, it seems wonky to me also. but it is the only way I have even gotten to even pull the correct column. I am trying to figure out how to make it not ignore the if statement .

Comment: You can definitely use `Where-Object` its much simpler in this case but its unclear why are you using `Out-File` to a path that has a `.csv` extension when what you're looking to do is export an array of values (PSComputerName values). Its also not clear if this is a new file or you're looking to _append_ to an existing CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter your output from `import-csv` using `where-object`, then export as a csv file using `export-csv`. Do it all in a single line by passing objects along the pipeline:

```
import-csv .\os.csv | Where-Object {$_.BuildNumber -ne "19045"} | Export-Csv -Path noncompliant.csv
```

### **Edit:** Output just the list of computer names to a file

In order to just output the computer names, use `Select-Object` (with the `-ExpandProperty` so you don't get the name of the field) and don't use `Export-Csv`:

```
import-csv .\os.csv | Where-Object {$_.BuildNumber -ne "19045"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PScomputername | out-file .\noncompliant.csv
```

Comment: Thank you. That is almost perfect. But I do need end up but nothing but the PSComputername. no headers or BuildNumber.